# How do I add a fix number of ytics for auto scaled yrange ([*:*]) in gnuplot?

Tags: csv, plot, graph, format, gnuplot

set ytics 5 # adds a tick mark at every 5 interval

I want to add exactly five (or n) tics for a graph with auto scaling on.

What are the ways to set exactly 5 (or n) ticks on a graph?

Comment: What is your terminal? An interactive terminal e.g. like wxt, qt or a file .pdf or .png?

Answer (score 0):

Leave the y axis autoscaling alone.  Turn off the y axis tickmarks.
Now define a y2 axis that the plot will not use.
We control the range, tickmarks, etc of this new axis.
Mirror the y2 axis tickmarks so they appear along both vertical edges of the plot.

```
unset ytics
set y2tics mirror
set y2range [0:5]
set y2tics 1 format ""   # no labels
plot DATA ...
```

[image]

As shown, this defines five *intervals* not five tickmarks and so there four marks between the top and bottom.  If you want six intervals, hence five tickmarks between top and bottom, change that to

```
set y2range [0:6]
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to have exactly N tics **with** tic labels.
You need to know that gnuplot's autoscale tries to find a range and tic intervals with "nice" even numbers. However, this might lead to getting too many tics (see e.g. [How to tweak automatic-tics-number in gnuplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54070640/7295599)).
The following example is a shortened version of this.

As far as I know, there is no easy gnuplot option to e.g. set approximately 5 tics or not more than 5 tics ensuring "nice" intervals.
If you force 5 tics, depending on the range you might end up with pretty odd numbers which is probably not what you want.

Since the autoscale plotting range, i.e. the `GPVAL_...` variables are only known **after** plotting, hence, you need to plot twice: first to get the range and second to set the tics distance to the desired interval.

In the following example the autoranges chosen by gnuplot are `xrange[0:10]` and `yrange[0:8]`. So, forcing 5 xtics result in "semi-odd" numbers, hence, forcing 6 xtics might be better.

**Script:** (e.g. for interactive wxt, qt, ... terminal)

```
### force fixed number of tics
reset session

$Data <<EOD
0.1  7.4
5.0  1.5
9.5  0.1
EOD

set autoscale
dxtic(n) = (GPVAL_X_MAX - GPVAL_X_MIN)/(n-1)
dytic(n) = (GPVAL_Y_MAX - GPVAL_Y_MIN)/(n-1)

plot $Data u 1:2 w lp pt 7

pause -1
set xtics dxtic(5)
set ytics dytic(5)
replot

pause -1
set xtics dxtic(6)
set ytics dytic(5)
replot
### end of script
```

**Result:**

first plot (automatic tics. Maybe a bit too many tics):

[image]

replot with forcing 5 xtics and 5 ytics:

[image]

replot with forcing 6 xtics and 5 ytics:

[image]