# Increasing the ytics step relatively

Tags: gnuplot

Is it possible to increase ytics step, for instance, two times? Or approach a current value? I generate several figures by a script and each has a different yrange. Thank you

```
set ytics <start>, <increment> ??
```

Comment: Default is autosetting of y-range and y-tics. What exactly in your case is not good with this? What do you mean with "increase y step two times"? `1.0, 2.0, 4.0, 8.0, 16.0, ...?` this would be `set logscale y 2`.  What do you mean with "approach a current value"? Please always make a concrete example what you got and what you would like to have.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77199181/7295599) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54070640/7295599) maybe answer your question?